# How can I add a .Equals() extension to an enumeration?

Tags: c#

I currently have the following code:

```
public enum FieldType
{
    Int,
    Year,
    String,
    DateTime
}
public enum DataType
{
    Int,
    String,
    DateTime
}
```

I would like to have an extension method for each so that I can do something like this:

```
FieldType fType = FieldType.Year;
DataType dType = DataType.Int;

fType.Equals(dType); //If fType is an Int/Year, and dType is an Int it should return true
dType.Equals(fType); //If dType is an Int, and fType is an Int/Year it should be true
```

Is there a way to create a .Equals extension, so that this will work out?

Comment: I'm confused. You're saying you want FieltType.Year to be "equal to" DataType.Int? What does that even mean?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior The purpose behind this is that Year is an int when it comes to data value and should be treated as such, but our formatted value may allow different default options for the user to select. For instance, if we were dealing with a normal int, we may offer "Currency" as a format option, but it doesn't make sense for a year.  Likewise, for year, we may offer a "Short Year" (2-digit) option, but that doesn't make sense for an int, even though when it comes to dealing with the data value, both are legitimate options.

Comment: So `FieldType.Int` == `DataType.Int` and `FieldType.Year` == `DataType.Int`, but `FieldType.Int` != `FieldType.Year`? That breaks the Transitive Property of Equality (http://www.mathwords.com/t/transitive_property.htm), so you should be using a method name that doesn't imply equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon said, reusing a framework's method name is not a very good idea.

But you could easily do something like that :

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsEquivalentTo(this FieldType field, DataType data)
    {
        return data.ToString() == field.ToString();
    }

    public static bool IsEquivalentTo(this DataType data, FieldType field)
    {
        return data.ToString() == field.ToString();
    }
}
```

or even better :

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsEquivalentTo(this Enum e1, Enum e2)
    {
        return e1.ToString() == e2.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that works with the desired behaviour of "If fType is an Int/Year, and dType is an Int it should return true" - because FieldType.Year and DataType.Int won't compare as true using your implementation.

Comment: I totally missed that, you're right Jon. I would better have to cancel my answer (I don't know if I can).

Answer (score 8):

Well you *could* write:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Equals(this FieldType field, DataType data)
    {
        return data.Equals(field);
    }

    public static bool Equals(this DataType data, FieldType field)
    {
        // Insert logic here
    }
}
```

I'm not sure I *would* though... because you're overloading `object.Equals` in an inconsistent manner. So if someone wrote:

```
object field = FieldType.Int;
Console.WriteLine(field.Equals(DataType.Int));
```

that would print False, because it would be using `object.Equals` instead of the extension method.

Comment: Jon is right. That would be very confusing. Rather then overriding Equals, it would be better to just make methods such as IsInteger(dType) or IsString(dType). That would make more sense since your not really testing for equality, per se

Comment: Yes, this. Just don't use the method name `Equals` because it already has another meaning.