# Add method to auto-generated class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, extension-methods, equals, edmx

How can I add `bool Equals(object obj)` method to class that is created automatically (in my case by edmx model).

One solution that I mean is to inherit this class and use this new class, but I'm looking for something different.

Comment: Use extension methods. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550551/how-can-i-add-a-equals-extension-to-an-enumeration

Comment: Please be clear: do you want to _override_ Equals?

Comment: Note: if you override Equals, you **must** override GetHashCode suitably too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class is partial, so you can create a new partial class.

```
public partial class MyClass
{
  bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    // code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just also found this solution, thanx

Answer (score -2):

You can use Extension Methods

```
public static class ExM
{
    public static bool Equals(this MyClass obj1, MyClass obj2)
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

It will add that method `Equals` in Intellisense of MyClass object so that when you call it like this

```
bool b = MyClassObject1.Equals(MyClassObject2);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but he was asking to add the method as an instance method. Your solution works, but it wasn't what he was asking for.